# how to multi band compress the low end?

Tags: mixing

i have a problem with my low end when i am mixing. because it seems sometimes my low end lack of good bottom up ,fat bass on some notes(my synth bass). i search and find out that if i use multi band compression, i could have a fat tight bass. and i did exactly what they do. i even try different mb compressors like c4,fabfilter,ozone and... but with no luck. it seems that even with mb compressor, my low bass, doesnt have that even sound. what did i miss? can anynody help me please?

Comment: You can’t add what’s not there. Most likely problem is whatever you are using for a bass sound doesn’t have the tone that you want. You have to get the right bass sound before you start mixing. Then in the mixing the only thing is to not mess it up.

Comment: yes.i know.i cant add whats not there. i didnt say its not there. actually it is. but some of my low bass notes are louder than the others. i want to have even sounds levels at my low bass so when i change the notes , it wont affect my low bass balance

Comment: I usually takes years and years of practice to learn to mix well. It's also possible that your listening system is not even with bass sounds. Usually a synth bass track is a lot more even than a bass guitar track, so you might double check by listening on different speakers to see if the imbalance changes with other speakers and if it does, then the problem isn't with the bass track. If it's definitely uneven on the bass track, then you'll just have to keep working and studying and practicing on the mix until it starts to come in line. It won't be easy.

Comment: yes i thought so as well. i thought its maybe because of my speakers. its m audio m3-6. but what about the analyzer? i use span and fabfilter . so for example at some notes, my bottom low end is at -6db and the other notes, it fall to -9 db. maybe my hearing and my speakers decieving me, but what about analayzer?

Comment: Fluctuations of 3 dB aren't such a big deal. Still, I suspect the real problem is that you don't properly understand how the synths you're using work. Am I correct to guess that you're using preset sounds? Make sure you know how these are built up, and what all the modulation etc. parameters do. You should also be able to build synth patches from scratch, without any presets.

Comment: ok.so u suggest that using the scratch will do any different? do u say that they make the scratches more simple? thanks.

Comment: Checkout the sound SE https://sound.stackexchange.com